# Conditionally rescaling a table

Tags: tables, conditionals, resize

I have some latex tables created programmatically by an external application I wrote. Some of them are larger than the `\textwidth`. In this case I need to rescale them to fit `\textwidth` (otherwise I leave them as they are). I know how to do the rescaling:

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
% code for my table
}
```

However, I do not know whether the table requires rescaling or not until I compile the latex code and see it for myself. I cannot come up with a reasonable estimate of their width based on the number of columns, as they contain different objects of variable size.

So my question is: is there a way, within latex, to measure the width of a table, given its code, and then conditionally apply the `\resizebox` to it?

For what it's worth, some of the tables I have use `\begin{tabular}` while some other use `\begin{tblr}` from the `tabularray` package.

EDIT: These tables contain symbols that scale very well. There can be very many columns. Line breaking is not an option and wouldn't help.

Comment: Rescaling tables is a bad idea. Instead you should choose a suitable font size. You could test different sizes and choose the one which will make the table fit. Have a look at the tcolorbox package and its fitting library for some inspiration.

Comment: Please tell us *why* some of your tables a too wide. Is it a failure to allow lne breaking is some cells? If not, what else?

Comment: don't use `\resizebox` on tables, you will get inconsistent font sizes but `\resizebox{\ifdim\textwidth>\width\width\else\textwidth\fi}{!}`

Comment: @Mico Tables contain symbols that scale very well. There can be very many columns. Line breaking is not an option.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand what "symbols that scale very well" may mean. If it is what I think it is, then why do you need a `tabular` (or `tblr`) environment? Please edit your posting to provide a pactical example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use \resizebox on tables, you will get inconsistent font sizes but

```
\resizebox{\ifdim\textwidth>\width\width\else\textwidth\fi}{!}
```

Does what you ask, generally better would be to measure the width (by saving in a box) and then if it is too large choosing `\small` or `\footnotesize` or whatever fits. But re-executing the table (as opposed to simply scaling it) means you have to worry about any counters or file writing that you need to avoid doing twice.